# User avatar not displayed in Django

Tags: django

I want to user have a avatar. So I created the model and the form.
Image is not displaying on the page. But form saves the image to folder. Where is mistake?

`request.user.avatar.url` doesn't work. Maybe the image is not attached to User? Thanks for the help

P.S. djagno-avatar is not good for me.

models.py

```
class Avatar(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True)
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to='user_avatars', null=True)
```

forms.py

```
class UserPhotoForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Avatar
        fields = ('avatar', )
        widgets = {
            'avatar': forms.FileInput(attrs={'class': 'input'}),
        }
```

views.py

```
def cabinet(request):
    user = request.user
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserPhotoForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=user)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
    else:
        form = UserPhotoForm()
    return render(request, 'account/cabinet/cabinet.html', {'form': form})
```

cabinet.html

```
<div class="avatar">
     {{ request.user.avatar.url }} #there is trying
     {{ request.user.avatar.avatar.url }}
     <img src="{{ request.user.avatar.avatar.url }}" alt="" width="80px" height="80px">
     <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
         {% csrf_token %}
         {{ form.as_p }}
         <input type="submit" id="file"/>
     </form>
```

Comment: {{request.user}} is displaying anything?

Comment: You are displaying the image before the user has been created.There lies the problem

Comment: Also to display the user avatar the user needs to be logged in. Have you created login system yet?

Comment: @sevdimali displays username in this case displays admin

Comment: @SaGaR yep, I have login system. Ok, but when I added a image, it should display after reload.

Comment: Try to login with another user and then it

Comment: Are you using pycharm or any ide. If yes then try to run the app from console.

Comment: @SaGaR tried with another user doesn't work. Btw, in admin in model Users should be field avatar? Yes, I'm using pycharm. From console not working too. Maybe in views.py make checking user.avtar and give that argument to context?

Comment: @SaGaR sure, have pillow and static enabled. With image everything is ok. Look, I requested user in views.py and  gave to the context. With username with email works, but with avatar not. When I try to user = request.user.avatar, I have traceback _User has no avatar._  When I try user = request.user
    a = Avatar.objects.get(user=user), I gave traceback _Avatar matching query does not exist_.I think the problem in model Avatar.

Comment: user = request.user
a = Avatar.objects.get(user=user).avatar.url
then in html i can display it img src="{{a}}"
I can even change it from admin. But on page change cannot. Now i think problem in forms.py, cuz in admin in model Avatar i have lots of picture without user.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 <img src="{{ request.user.avatar.url }}" alt="" width="80px" height="80px">
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ImageField

Comment: Doesn't work. In console <img src(unknown) alt="" width="80px" height="80px">

Answer (score 0):

Found the main problem you are never storing your avatar model in db. As you are giving it the instance of your user. Because of that your Avatar model is not stored.
You have to use

```
def cabinet(request):
    user = request.user
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserPhotoForm(request.POST,request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            temp=form.save(commit=False)
            temp.user = user
            temp.save()
    else:
        form = UserPhotoForm()
    return render(request, 'account/cabinet/cabinet.html', {'form': form})
```

Try that

Comment: I get error UNIQUE constraint failed: account_avatar.user_id. I consider, the problem is that when I fill the form, django doesn't know about user. But I can change photo from admin. There is something :)

Comment: I suggest you to delete all the users and avatars or better drop both tables and start fresh@ElevatorUpvote if it helps

Comment: Can u give me ur telegram? Or write me please https://t.me/fsociety0k